# Bitrix не меняется подменю раздела, в чем моя ошибка?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не меняется меню подраздела, может не по тому пути меняю? 
Путь: /bitrix/components/bitrix/catalog/templates/.default/bitrix/catalog.section.list/.default/template.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу его удались совсем, чтобы не было или поменять стиль класса, очень уж ужасно выглядит.

Comment: скорее всего, компонент кастомизирован, а, значит, должен лежать в шаблоне: /bitrix/templates/ваш_шаблон/components/bitrix/

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо, какие-то теги меняются, но именно этот элемент остается как и прежде неизменен

Answer (score 0):

Вы изменяете на данный момент ядро битрикса и этого категорически не рекомендуется делать.
 
У вас есть шаблон сайта в нем скорее всего есть копия этого компонента и его шаблона.
Что бы найти шаблон нужно :

- Элемент списка
- Включить режим правки
- Навести мышь на область которая вам нужно изменить
- Увидеть что область обвелась и появилась шестеренка
- Нажать шестеренку и отредактировать шаблон компонента 
   
   
  https://yadi.sk/i/ZZkzM44GHuvSVQ
  https://yadi.sk/i/utcFbBvBe6Luzg

Comment: спасибо, самым первым пробовал так сделать, но безуспешно